# Is there a way to remove the time axis for the day view in Fullcalendar.io?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

We are using fullcalendar.io https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat.

My usecase is to show two calendars right next to eachother, so I only want to show the time axis for one calendar.

By time axis I mean the time interval labels (1:00, 1:30, 2:00) etc.

Comment: No you can't do that unfortunately. Why do you want to show two calendars side by side though? Perhaps there is  a better way to implement your overall requirement.

Comment: @ADyson One person wants to schedule an appointment, and needs to look at the calendars of two others.

Comment: You can just show all the appointments on one calendar. You can perhaps put them in different colours to distinguish them, feed them from different Event Sources (if that's useful) and/or use the (premium) Resources feature to deliniate the different people / calendars, but all in one fullCalendar instance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Adyson, I'l take it back to my team and see what we can do. It's just good to know that you can't in-fact do it and I'm not just missing it :)

Comment: No problem. Obviously using only one instance also takes up a lot less space on your page and removes potential UX issues such as one calendar showing March while the other one is on April, or similar.